# Any way to install mysql2 GEM without installing mysql server locally

Tags: mysql, ruby

I want to use a remote MySQL database. Is there any way to install mysql2 gem in OS X **without** installing MySQL server locally?

Update: I found the solution. Actually, I don't need the MySQL server installed locally, I just need to install the adapter as follow..

```
brew install mysql-connector-c
```

Followed by,

```
gem install mysql2
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the gem needs mysql installed locally to run as it uses some underlying c libraries for the client. I don't think it can work without it.

Check out https://github.com/tmtm/ruby-mysql which i believe is native ruby and may not need it, but is not compatible with 4.1.x.